# Running .innerHTML from a php file to change an HTML element

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm an old school RPGILE programmer trying to create a website.  How do I get `.innerHTML` working from a PHP file (with HTML embed) to change an HTML element text?

My PHP (file) code:

```
$txt = 'First Name is required!';
sInnerHtml($reginfo, $txt);    
// $reginfo is the name of the HTML element
```

`sInnerHtml` points to a (PHP file) service function:

```
function sInnerHtml($element, $text)
{
echo <<<_END
<script>
    jO("$element").innerHTML = "$text"
</script>
_END;
}
```

`jO` points to a JavaScript alias:

```
function jO(obj)
{
    if(typeof obj === 'object')
        return obj
    else
        return document.getElementById(obj)
}
```

Comment: Your code example is a little confusing—but from what I can see so far I'd say your biggest issue is related to the jO function. You're passing 1 parameter, but then a load of string after it, that the function won't accept. Either move the innerHTML string to the jO function or apply a different logic. I'm assuming you must have some errors in your browser's inspect-element/console too. I would use that as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was able to figure it out that the call to that function was never happening.  This style of coding is driving me crazy!